# Determining the probability of at least one of a subset of probabilities occurring

Tags: probability

I have a set of percentages, they are:

[$7\%$, $8.4\%$, $10.2\%$, $9.8\%$, $44.5\%$]

For each percent in the array, I am using a random number generator between 0 and 100 (to two decimal places). If the random number is equal or less than the number in the array, it means that number HIT and the game is over. If it's higher, I go on to the next number.

What is the probability that none of the numbers will hit and I will go through all seven percentages without a number hitting, and how is this calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Let the list of probabilities $L=[p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n]$. Ignoring the discretization error (which would just change the actual numbers in $L$ slightly), the probability none of the variables $X_i\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p_i)$ being one/happening is
$$
p = (1-p_1)(1-p_2)\dots(1-p_n).
$$
In your case, this gives
$$
p = (1-7\%)(1-8.4\%)(1-10.2\%)(1-9.8\%)(1-44.5\%)= 38.3\%.
$$